# Find records that do not have a corresponding record in the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the following table:

```
 ID | JobID | Data   | ResultType
---------------------------------
  1 | 12345 | XXXX   | 0
  2 | 12345 | YYYY   | 1
  3 | 23456 | AAAA   | 0
  4 | 23456 | BBBB   | 1
  5 | 34567 | FOOB   | 0
  6 | 45678 | BARB   | 0
```

Now I need to build a query that delivers all `JobIDs` where there is no entry with a `ResultType = 1`

**EDIT1:**

So at the end, I want to result that delivers only `JobIDs` 34567 and 45678, because there is no record with a `ResultType = 1` for those `JobIDs`.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way (not tested):

```
SELECT JobId FROM Jobs GROUP BY jobId HAVING max(ResultType) = 0
```

Answer (score 4):

Use this query:

```
SELECT JobID 
From table1 a 
WHERE NOT EXISTS
 (SELECT 1 FROM table1 b WHERE b.JobID = a.JobID AND b.ResultType = 1)
```

Answer (score 3):

Something like

```
select * from jobs where jobId not in 
          (select jobId from jobs where resultType = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT JobID FROM <TableName> WHERE ResultType <> 1
```

Is this what you want ???

Comment: thanks. no, but i changed my post to make it clear what i want.